# Rails google analytics measuring customer retention

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, google-analytics

I'm running a website made using rails/ angular and I need to measure when a user returns to the site. I want to use this data to set up conversion tracking for the site (if a user returns, it's a conversion).

Any ideas how to set something like this up using rails/ google analytics?

Answer (score 0):

Google have a nice checklist to go through what's needed to set up GA on your site. Click on the links to get details on how to go about it:

http://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/analytics/learn/setupchecklist.html

Alternatively, look into cookies. The scenario would be that a first time visitor gets a cookie saved to their cache. When they return, a JS conditional statement would +=1 to a log, since they already have the cookie saved.

Good luck.